# how to an object sticks to another object and these come back to start point in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, projectile

I would like to catch an object with another object. And then carry it to the start point of first object, in 2D. 
I'm throwing an object to another object with a constant velocity.
The first one collides with a second one, after that I defined reverse velocity of the first one to the standing second object. When a collision happens (onCollisonListener) it doesn't turn back naturally, so the angle of turning back is wrong.

They go everywhere randomly. How can I make it so that turning back functions properly? **Which function could I use?** I am using only velocity.x and velocity.y
*Thanks for reading my question and for your help,
Sincerely Yours.*

Comment: If you still need some help, can you post code of your "reverse velocity" calculations? Also screenshot of whats happening would be nice too.

Comment: You should be more exact in what you need. Do you want the 2nd object to attach fixed (like it's stuck) or more soft (like on a string)? You can re-parent it or use physics links.
Also, it is very important if you use Rigidbodies or not.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
public class Catcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 startingPoint;

    void Awake()
    {
        startingPoint = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Your moving code
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
         if(other.tag == "someTag")
         {
             other.transform.parent = transform;
             StartCoroutine("MoveBack");
         }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveBack()
    {
        while(transform.position != startingPoint)
        {
            // Move this towards starting point
            // Use Vector2 functions like Lerp, MoveTowards or SmoothDamp
            // Could also use Mathf functions
            yield null;
        }
    }
}
```

And maybe add a flag/check to know if the object is moving back or forward.